# Applying the initial conditions on a Power Series

Tags: power-series, initial-value-problems

Consider the IVP:
\begin{equation}
y''+y'=xy\quad;\quad y(0)=2,y'(0)=1
\end{equation}
Using the Power Series method to get the solution, we'll initially write:
\begin{equation}
y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\quad;\quad y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}
\end{equation}
Applying the initial conditions, one should get $a_0=2$ and $a_1=1$. And that's where I have a little conceitual confusion. The argument I would use to illustrate that would simply be:
\begin{equation}
y=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n\Longrightarrow y(0)=a_0=2\quad;\quad y'=a_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}\Longrightarrow y'(0)=a_1=1
\end{equation}
Since the other terms will clearly vanish. That's a decent approach, but it seems to me to be more of an adjustment than a proper argument. If we, without doing the previous development, tried to evaluate $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$, the other therms would continue to vanish, but we'd get $0^0$ forms at $n=0$. Well, that must be a way to argue that this continues to give $a_0$ and $a_1$ regardless. I thought about using the fact:
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0}t^0=1
\end{equation}
But it seems like a rather tautological argument. How can I formally develop a argument for that?

Comment: When working with power series, the convention $0^0=1$ is adopted.

Comment: While it is nice to write the first term as $a_0 x^0$ so that the entire sum can be written in summation notation, we really just mean that it is a constant $a_0$, there is only any (possible) distinction when $x=0$.